# Can the IEnumerable.Zip resultsSelector add more than one element to the result Enumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I am generating two lists which will contain the same number and order of objects, but the will have different property values since the second list is an updated version of the data.

I need to reconsile both lists into one, taking some data from the old list and some from the new. `IEnumerable.Zip` seems perfect for this task, except that under certain conditions when comparing the two objects, I will want the resultSelector function to return two objects.

Is this possible or does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Zip doesn't do what you want at all. It combines two sequences pairwise *only* without checking any conditions or if the elements match. Sounds like you need `Join` instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The OP said it contains the same number *and order* of objects, so it sounds like Zip is fine.

Comment: Zip can't emit multiple records per pair though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Not on its own, no - but it doesn't need to. It's got one job, which is to zip the pairs together. Then SelectMany is the normal way of handling the "convert one item into potentially-multiple" items - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to combine `Zip` and `SelectMany`:

```cs
// Assuming .NET Core 3.0 or later; in other versions you'd need to provide
// a selector to the Zip method, which would just return the tuple.
var result = first.Zip(second)
                  .SelectMany(tuple =>
                  {
                      // Deconstruct the tuple into the two elements
                      var (x, y) = tuple;
                      // Yield two items case
                      if (x.Id != y.Id)
                      {
                          yield return x;
                          yield return y;
                      }
                      else
                      // Yield one item case
                      {
                          yield return x;
                      }
                  });
```

(You may well want to extract that logic into a separate method, of course. We can't give a more concrete example to suit your situation as the question doesn't give a concrete example of what you're doing.)